# Ruby how to get array with boolean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

i would like to get a arrau of boats, but i would like that just show the boats with rent boolean set to true.

how can acomplish this?

i've added:

```
@boats = Boat.where(rent: true)
```

But did not worked

i even tried the method model

```
def rents
    self.class.where(rent: true)
  end
```

and did not worked either

Comment: Do you want an array of the names? or you you want a hash of objects? `@boats = Boat.where(rent: true)` should've worked if you have your tables setup properly for a set of objects.

Comment: What do you mean by _did not worked_? Was there an error? What was the error message and how did the stack trace look like? Or did you receive an unexpected result? How did it look like?

Comment: Your code seems OK, do you get an error when you try to execute the code? that might help.

Comment: `@boats = Boat.where(rent: true)` should work. Make sure that you actually have boats with rent = true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
<% @boats.where(:rent=>true).each do |t| %> 
 <%= t.name %>
<%end%>
<%= @boats.where(:rent=>true).all %>
```

or

```
<% if boats.where(:rent=>true).exists?  %>
 <%= t.name %>
<%end%>
```

or

```
def rents
 @boats.where(:rent=>true).all
end
```

Comment: nourza! the array on view works fine but not on the controller! 
thank you very much